# Change button text after popUp whit React and sweetalert2-react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sweetalert2

i m learning react and i trying to change my button text after sweetAlert2-react popup.
The original text on the button is 'ACTIVE' and
If i choose OK on the popup the text on the button must be 'activated' and if y choose CANCEL 'disabled'..

I do not know how or where to do the IF iteration
any help?

here is my code:

```
<button onClick={() => this.setState({ show: true })}>ACTIVE</button> <SweetAlert show={this.state.show} showCancelButton={this.state.show} title="Are you shore?" onConfirm={() => this.setState({ show: false })} />
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally set the string internal to the button.

```
<button>
    {this.state.active === 'active' && <div>ok</div>}
    {this.state.active === 'disabled' && <div>idk</div>}
<button>
```

If there are only two states consider a ternary operator.

```
<button>
    {this.state.active === 'active' ? <div>ok</div> : <div>idk</div>}
<button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save the button's text in the state, (ex: `this.state.buttonText`), then you'll be able to set the `buttonText` when user click on `OK`/`Cancel` button.

You can use a common method (in the below example `hideAlert`) for manage both events (ok and cancel) and inside it, set the button's text.

See the following example please ([click here to run](https://codesandbox.io/s/1ywl2rv85j)):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class HelloWorld extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      alert: null,
      button: "active"
    };
  }

  showAlert() {
    const getAlert = () => (
      <SweetAlert
        show={this.state.show}
        showCancel
        onConfirm={() => this.hideAlert("disabled")}
        onCancel={() => this.hideAlert("active")}
      >
        Are you sure?
      </SweetAlert>
    );

    this.setState({
      alert: getAlert()
    });
  }

  hideAlert(text) {
    this.setState({
      alert: null,
      button: text
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: "20px" }}>
        <button onClick={() => this.showAlert()}>
          {this.state.button}
        </button>
        {this.state.alert}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

I hope it helps you, bye.